# Loss Returns NaN When Using Regulizers On LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

When I train my LSTM model, it returns nan for the loss

- I am using a single layer LSTM with a Dense softmax layer at the end for classification output
- Adam optimizer
- Categorical crossentropy loss function
- Relu activation

For some reason when I use regulizers of any kind on the LSTM layer I get NaN for the loss.
Also this only occurs when I make the LSTM layer over 128 units, so I can get rid of it if I get rid of the regularization or make the network 128 or less units.
I have already confirmed that there are no NaNs in the input.
I'm wondering why this happens, and how it is possible to regularize larger LSTM layers.

Here's my code:

```
def build_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(130, batch_input_shape=(None,90,5), return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=0.1, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
return(model)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you normalizing the data before using the model? What is the min and max values?

Comment: Yes I am using percent changes from the stock price of the day before to predict the next day's movement. The highest the values usually get is around 0.1, and -0.1 on the bottom side.  I've also figured out that the entire model won't fit without regularization if the LSTM layers are bigger than 128 units. I believe this is a glitch of some kind with Keras, Tensorflow, or CUDA

Comment: is it fixed now? Do you still get nans?

Comment: Yes, it happens only with LSTM layers and only when they are over 128 units in size